# download using wget in perl

Tags: perl, file, wget, seek, tell

New to Perl, hope someone could kindly explain the following questions related to this code:

```
$url ="some url";
open FH, "wget -q -O- $url|" or die;  
while(<FH>){  
  ...  
}
```

1. what does the the second `-` in `-O-` mean?
2. what does the `|` in `$url |` mean?
3. I tried to do a seek with the FH like this:

```
 $url ="some url";
 open FH, "wget -q -O- $url|" or die;  
 seek(FH, 14000, 1);
```

but if I echo the position with `echo tell(FH)`, I get 0, anyone know why couldn't I seek the FH? Thanks

Comment: Why shell out to wget when Perl has LWP (which has a proper Perlish API)?

Comment: I am sure there are multiple and better ways to do things, but I just want to understand the above code well enough first, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-O-` argument tells `wget` to output to standard output (i.e. your console/terminal), not to a file.

The pipe in the open call is a [pipe open](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html#Pipe-Opens). The file handle will be connected to the process's output (in this case, to what `wget` outputs).

A `tell` call on this type of filehandle doesn't really make sens. The underlying thing is a stream, not a file. `tell` can return [different things on streams](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tell.html), it depends on the OS.

Comment: Thanks for answering, appreciated it

Answer (score 1):

> what does the the second - in -O- mean?

From `man wget`

> The documents will not be written to the appropriate files, but all
>   will be concatenated together and written to file.  If - is used as
>   file, documents will be printed to standard output, disabling link
>   conversion.  (Use ./- to print to a file literally named -.)

---

> what does the | in $url | mean?

It isn't **in** $url, it is after it.

From the perldoc for [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)

> if the filename ends with a '|' , the filename is interpreted as a command that pipes output to us

Comment: Thanks for answering, appreciated it

Answer (score 0):

The second `-` means that you want `wget` to output to the standard output rather than to a file. The `|` means that you are opening a pipe to the newly created `wget` process and you can read its output.

Seeking makes sense for files on disk but not for pipes. The output is produced as the program is executed so it's not possible to "jump in the future".

Comment: Thanks for answering, appreciated it